# Как изменить часовой пояс для created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
[1] pry(main)> Time.now
=> 2016-04-02 17:26:26 +0300
[4] pry(main)> Post.last.votes.create(money: 20)
[9] pry(main)> Vote.last.created_at
=> Sat, 02 Apr 2016 14:26:50 UTC +00:00
[6] pry(main)> Time.zone.name
=> "UTC"
```

Как изменить часовой пояс на `UTC +03:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Ruby on Rails принято соглашение: календарные данные на уровне базы данных хранятся в формате UTC. Однако, при выводе пользователю их формат изменяется в соответствии с настройками приложения, заданными в файле config/application.rb. Например, московское время можно задать следующим образом.

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.time_zone = 'Europe/Moscow'
    ...
  end
end
```

Причем замена проводится очень интеллектуально, для 2014 года у вас будет учитываться зимнее время, а после его отмены уже нет.